# Calculating cellsize of EsriASCⅡ data

Tags: qgis, dem, esri-ascii-raster

I'm having trouble to calculate the cellsize of Esri ASCII data.
I would like to use meteorological data from JMA following data with QGIS3 software which is used
in my workplace.

http://database.rish.kyoto-u.ac.jp/arch/jmadata/data/jma-radar/synthetic/original/2014/08/09/Z__C_RJTD_20140809000000_RDR_JMAGPV__grib2.tar
※Z__C_RJTD_20140809000000_RDR_JMAGPV_Ggis1km_Prr10lv_ANAL_grib2.bin

This data's mesh size is 1km square.
ncols 2560
nrows 3360
xllcorner 118⇒degree
yllcorner 48⇒degree
catalog(written in Japanese) https://www.data.jma.go.jp/add/suishin/catalogue/format/ObdObs001_format.pdf

But I don't have any idea how to decide (calculate) correct cellsize parameter.

Could you give me a hand?

Comment: There isn't enough information in you question to compute pixel size (you need either pixelsize or diagonal corners)

Comment: Abstract from catalog  48.0N to 20.0N   118.0E to 150.0E

Comment: the data is in .bin format. Is this an ASCII? What software are you using to open this?

Comment: use `gdalinfo` to find out "everything" about your raster (including the correct type)